# Is this the correct way to reconstitute a given user's session?

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-cookies

I have the function as follows:

```
 $sid = mysql_real_escape_string( $_COOKIE['session_id'] );
if( $sid ) { session_id( $sid ); }

// Start session
if( !session_start() ) { die( 'Session could not be started.' ); }
$sid = session_id();

// Validate session id
 $user = $this->validateSessionId( $sid );

if( $user ) {
    if( !$user['uid'] ) {
        trigger_error( '`Services->__construct()` - Could not find user by session id \''.(string)$sid.'\'.',
                E_USER_ERROR );
    }

    $_SESSION['uid'] = $user['uid'];
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user['name'];
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user['email'];
    $_SESSION['user_created'] = $user['created'];
}

// If no valid session id, user is anonymous
else {
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = 'Anonymous';
    $_SESSION['user_created'] = time();
}
```

When a user first logs in, a cookie is created for them called `session_id` with the id of their current session.  This id is also added to a database table.  My understanding is that the session eventually expires on both the client and the server, but a cookie and a database entry can be set to last as long as I'd want.

`validateSessionId` checks a table of session ids in the database.  If the session is found, and hasn't last been accessed more than 30 days ago (it's removed from the table if so), an associative array from the user list representing the user associated with that session id.  That user's data is then loaded into the current session.

Am I understanding the workings of this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `session_id()` business can be avoided. PHP will automatically check for the presence of a session cookie when you call session_start(), and retrieve the session's ID at that time. You're just duplicating what's already done for you.

Your code presumes that the cookie PHP is sending out to track the session is actually a permanent cookie. Usually PHP sends out a session cookie only (e.g. delete when browser is closed). As such, the user will not have ANY session cookie when they come back to the site, and will get a brand new session each time.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have mentioned the cookie value `session_id` is stored upon first logging in, and is necessary to reconstitute the session of the user after its expiration.

Comment: Yes, but if the client browser has forgotten about that cookie, you'll end up with an orphan session record in the database. The user will come in, have no cookie, so session_start() will create a NEW session ID.

Comment: Hmm.  Would a solution to that be to erase all session entries in the table for that user when they login again?  They'd have to login again anyway without that session cookie...

Comment: I guess you could have your login code check if the user's got stale sessions and delete them or copy those stale sessions' data over to the new one. Depends on what your needs/wants are.

Comment: Well it might be more secure(?) to invalidate old sessions if a user logs in again.  That could be a pain if they're wanting to use a given account on multiple machines, though...